# Unable to Retrieve data from dynamically linked select drop down - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I working on a dynamically linked Drop Down menu where it should retrieve the data based on the chosen value.

I am trying to display bank detail based on District > municipality > Bank info

I am able to retrieve the list successfully for first dropdown. But I am unable to retrieve further more data from it The data is returned empty[image: The second dropdown return empty results].

[image: The url returns 200 status code]

I am new to laravel and development. Thank you for assistance.

Adding to this I will add one more question, 
If I would like to add more tables along with Banks on the selection of drop down selection, eg: transactions. How do I achieve it?

**index.blade.php**

```
 <div class="container">
        {!!Form::open()!!}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""> District</label>
            <select name="district_option" id="district_option" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District --------</option>
                @foreach ($districts as $key => $district)
                <option value="{{$district->id}}">{{$district->district_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for=""> Municipality</label>
            <select name="municipal_option" id="municipal_option" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District First--------</option>
            </select>
        </div>
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr> 

           <td> Bank Name</td>
        <td>Bank Acc No </td>
        <td>Bank IFSC Code</td>
        </tr>        
    </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr> 
                        {{-- <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td> --}}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
</table>
        {!!Form::close()!!}
```

**Script**

```
   $('#district_option').on('change',function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var district_id = e.target.value;
        var BASEURL = "{!! url('/admin/bank/') !!}";
        console.log(district_id);
        $.get( BASEURL + '/municipalview?district_id=' + district_id, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('#municipal_option').empty();
            $('#municipal_option').append('<option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">------ Select District First--------</option>');
         $.each(data,function(index, municipalObj){
            $('#municipal_option').append('<option value="'+ municipalObj.id +'"> '+ municipalObj.municipal_name +' </option>');
               })
                });
                }); 


        $('#municipal_option').on('change',function(e){
        // console.log(e);  
        var municipal_id = e.target.value; 
        var BASEURL = "{!! url('/admin/bank/') !!}";
        console.log(municipal_id);
        $.get( BASEURL + '/bankview?bank_id=' + municipal_id, function(data){
            console.log(data);

                });
                });
```

My routes files:

//add bank Details

```
Route::resource('bank', 'bankController');
Route::get('admin/bank/municipalview/', 'bankController@municipalView');
Route::get('admin/bank/bankview/', 'bankController@bankView');
```

**bankController File**

```
 public function municipalView()
{


    $districts_id = Input::get('district_id');
    $municipalities = Municipality::where('district_id', '=', $districts_id )->get();
    return response()->json($municipalities) ;
}   

public function bankView()
{

    $municipals_id = Input::get('municipal_id');
    $banks = Bank::where('district_id', '=', $municipals_id )->get();
    return response()->json($banks) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The challenge currently is that you have two subsequent queries, where your blade template will render dynamically only the results of the first. You have a number of options:

A) preload all data, and send them to the client side and let Javascript handle it. E.g. you'll send an object like:

```
{regionA: ["bank1", "bank2", "bank3"], regionB ["bank4, "bank4", "bank5"] }
```

Then create options dynamically through javascript based on the structure.

B) Let javascript (AJAX) handle the second query for a deeper level of data and fill in the options. There are libraries that could help with this (for example Selectize.js).

C) There are high level front-end frameworks such as Vue.js that could help with managing the 'state' of the client browser. This might be something to look into if you want to do more complex logic client-side.

### Update:

Looking at your code, I think the problem is how the request data gets passed to your controller methods. The quick fix is to pass a (Request $request) in the function and see what gets passed on - but I would suggest to spend some time on Eloquent relationships and see how you can have the ORM of Laravel (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) do this for you. Briefly, you could have Routes like this:

```
Route::get('admin/bank/municipalview/{District}', 'bankController@municipalView');
```

And then a controller like this:

```
 public function municipalView(Disctrict $district)
{

    $municipalities = District::municipalities();
    return response()->json($municipalities) ;
}
```

and make sure that you have a Disctrict model (php Artisan make Model)

in the model you can then define the relationship:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Disctrict           

 /**
 * Get the municipalities for a district.
 */
public function municipalities()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Municipality');
   }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed you're well underway with approach B, let me check the javascript to see if something is off there.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. I will surely try to touch these steps in future development.

The issue was in my script - 
`var municipal_id = e.target.value; 
        var BASEURL = "{!! url('/admin/bank/') !!}";
        console.log(municipal_id);
        $.get( BASEURL + '/bankview?bank_id=' + municipal_id, function(data)`
I replaced the `url /bankview?bank_id=` to  `/bankview?municipal_id=`

and it worked :)